# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error processing condition on SecurityAutoConfiguration.authenticationEventPublisher

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

Running a program occurs

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error processing condition on org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.servlet.SecurityAutoConfiguration.authenticationEventPublisher.

I have no clue wha's the problem. Maybe, versions are too different or something's wrong with autoconfigure. I'd be greatful for any solution

MvcConfig class:

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ViewControllerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;

@Configuration
public class MvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry){
        registry.addViewController("/login").setViewName("login");
    }
}
```

WebSecurityConfig class:

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.provisioning.InMemoryUserDetailsManager;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity

public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
   @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http)throws Exception{
       http
               .authorizeRequests()
               .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
               .anyRequest().authenticated()
               .and()
               .formLogin()
               .loginPage("/login")
               .permitAll()
               .and()
               .logout()
               .permitAll();
   }

   @Bean
    @Override
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService(){
       UserDetails user=
               User.withDefaultPasswordEncoder()
                       .username("user")
                       .password("password")
                       .roles("USER")
                       .build();
       return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(user);
   }
}
```

application.properties:

```
jdbc=mysql://localhost:3306/registration?useUnicode=true&serverTimezone=UTC+3&useSSL=true&verifyServerCertificate=false
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/registration
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=pass
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect

spring.mustache.servlet.expose-request-attributes=true
```

pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.work</groupId>
    <artifactId>Dormitory</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>Dormitory</name>
    <description>Project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <spring-security.version>5.3.4.RELEASE</spring-security.version>
        <spring.version>5.2.8.RELEASE</spring.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mustache</artifactId>
        </dependency>



        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

I tried to change version in pom.xml

```
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <spring-security.version>5.3.4.RELEASE</spring-security.version>
        <spring.version>5.2.8.RELEASE</spring.version>
    </properties>
```

into

```
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <spring-security.version>5.3.4.RELEASE</spring-security.version>
        <spring.version>5.3.4.RELEASE</spring.version>
    </properties>
```

thar didn't help. I want a program to run as a "log in" page